# Pop up menu with icons in android

Tags: android, menu, icons

Is there a good way to use icons with pop up menu. I have searched a lot and seen several examples. None of them are good. So is there a alternative to use pop up with icons. Actually, i have to implement the things shown in the picture[image]

Comment: in your alerdialog.xml you can design

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_alert_dialoges.htm refer this url link

Comment: by using custom theme you can achieve this. and for specific item you can set icon like this  android:icon="@drawable/myprofile" in menu.xml file

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, but is that possible to set dialog in certain position in screen?

Comment: RamBabu, yes you can code it like it, but it does not work. i mean, it will not be shown